# Asternet AMI Send Command c#

Tags: c#, asterisk, asteriskami, asternet

Please tell me how to send commands (e.g.: sip show peers) via asternet (c#). Any help or link will be highly appreciated.

Like:

```
AsterNET.Manager.Response.ManagerResponse response = SendAction("sip show peers");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"sip show peers" is COMMAND.

You have send action COMMAND.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_Command

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. But I want to ask how to do this in c#. Can you please show me some code snippets or links.

Comment: I was juggling around for more than two days but can't find a way to do some action (ask some commands as we asked with putty). Any help would be highly appreciated. I want to do this in my c# code.

Comment: Above unswer have all info you requested. Acordinly to SO rules you have do some efforts yourself

Comment: AsterNET.Manager.Action.CommandAction cmdAction = new CommandAction();

            cmdAction.Command = txtCommand.Text;//"core show channels";
            response = manager.SendAction(cmdAction);